# Manually re-sync with AzureADConnect

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

We recently decided to go towards O365.
During the initial deployment I installed the AzureADConnect Program and set it up.
Now all my AD Users are in the Office Portal (and the AzureAD).

BUT
my user is double.
In Hindsight that makes sense, as I had an account First.Lastname@company.com on the account before.
now I have that account (which is from AzureAD) and First.Lastname0815@companycom.onmicrosoft.com, which is from my on-prem AD.

Any idea how to fix that?
I deleted the AzureAD-Account, and hoped, that Azure would re-sync correctly.

I tried to delete the "wrong" Azure-AD Account, to have it re-synced, but I can not do that (as it states that it is synced from a local server)

Google did not give me an idea, as I am not exactly sure what to look for :-/

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty OU in your on premises AD.

Reconfigure Azure AD Connect to synchronize only this OU. This will delete the Office 365 users that were synched incorrectly.

Connect to Office 365 with Powershell and remove the users from the Office 365 recycle bin:

```
(Remove-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName First.Lastname0815@companycom.onmicrosoft.com -RemoveFromRecycleBin)
```

Create a UPN Suffix on premises that matches the UPN Suffix of your existing/original Office 365 users (@company.com). Set this UPN suffix on all of your on premises user accounts.

Reconfigure Azure AD Connect to sync the entire domain.

This should then synchronize your on premises users with your existing Office 365 users.

Comment: Just to add to Joeqwerty comment, you might want to run through the remove-msoluser on multiple users with a loop if there are more than one user. The removefromrecyclebin will permanently remove them, so you can start all over again

Comment: Hi,
thank you for your answers :-)

Which option of the 9 the AD Connect util gives me do I use?
the third one "change syncronisation options" (translation by me)
Seems to be the best guess.